# What is differece between token-level and segment-level in NLP task?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

Actually, I am not so understand about token..
When I read googleresearch/bert model, I see these words.

```
# In the demo, we are doing a simple classification task on the entire   
# segment.  
#   
# If you want to use the token-level output, use model.get_sequence_output()   # instead.
```

Can anyone make an example about token-level and segment-level classification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segment-level classification means that each segment will have one label, for example, a classifier which categorises a movie review as good or bad. There is only one output label for the entire input sequence.

Token-level classification means that each token will be given a label, for example a part-of-speech tagger will classify each word as one particular part of speech. Each token (element in the sequence) will have a corresponding label in the output.

If you're not sure what a token is, you can start by thinking of it as each word in a sentence, but to be more correct, look at https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tokenization-1.html. Depending on how you tokenise and preprocess your text, tokens can be words, punctuation symbols, special markers, subword-level symbols, etc.